# Create a DELETE statement that deletes Models that haven’t had a purchase since December 31st 2014

Tags: database-design, subquery, sqlite, table, delete

We are given 5 tables.

Orders

```
    Order number (Primary Key)

    Date of order

    Customer ID (Primary Key for Customers table)

    Serial Number (Primary Key for Machines table)
```

Customers

```
    ID (Primary Key)

    Name

    Phone Number

    Street (ie. 505 Ramapo Valley Road)

    City (ie. Mahwah)

    State

    Zip
```

Machines

```
    Serial Number (Primary Key)

    Model Number (Primary Key for Models table)
```

Model

```
    ID (Primary key)

    Speed

    RAM

    HD

    Price

    Manufacturer ID (Primary key for Manufacturer table)
```

Manufacturer

```
    ID (Primary Key)

    Name

    Phone Number

    Email Address
```

Our task is to create an SQL statement which will delete tuples from the Models table which haven't had a purchase since December 31st 2014.

The following is what I have managed to come up with thus far:

```
DELETE FROM Model

WHERE ID NOT IN

(

    SELECT Model.ID

    FROM Model

    INNER JOIN Machines

        ON Model.ID = Machines.ModelNo

    INNER JOIN Orders

        ON Machines.SerialNo = Orders.SerialNo

    WHERE OrderDate > 2015 

    GROUP BY Model.ID

);
```

Please let me know how I can fix this SQL statement, I believe the problem is either in the first or second line or possibly both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is you're using an `INNER JOIN` between `Machines` and `Orders` which means only return the rows that match (in other words, only the rows where `Orders` exist). Rather you should use an `OUTER JOIN`, in this case a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-left-join/) (which can simply be written as `LEFT JOIN`) so you get all the rows of `Models` and `Machines`, and the ones that don't have `Orders` will show a `NULL` value for the columns in the `Orders` table. Then you can use the `WHERE` clause to filter out anything but the rows without `Orders` by saying `WHERE Orders.SerialNo IS NULL` like so:

```
DELETE FROM Model
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT Model.ID
    FROM Model
    INNER JOIN Machines
        ON Model.ID = Machines.ModelNo
    LEFT JOIN Orders
        ON Machines.SerialNo = Orders.SerialNo
        AND Orders.OrderDate >= '2015-01-01' 
    WHERE Orders.SerialNo IS NULL
    GROUP BY Model.ID
);
```

The other issue you had was your `OrderDate` field is likely storing more than just the year (I'm assuming), so you need to specify the whole date (not just the year) when you do a direct comparison. I fixed that in the above query as well.

Please read the resource I linked above on `LEFT JOINS` along with the other resources I provided you on your last post, specifically understanding the different join types and when to use them are very important concepts.

Comment: I understand what you are doing to an extent, but I would like to ask why for the second line we wrote "WHERE ID NOT IN"? I am asking this because if the second WHERE clause is true (WHERE Orders.SerialNo IS NULL), wouldn't it mean that if ID is IN this subquery, then it has NULL for Orders.SerialNo which tells us that it has no orders after '2015-01-01'? Please let me know.

Comment: @DonaldAlesson Sorry that was leftover from your original query that I copied and reformatted. I just fixed my answer to actually correctly say `WHERE ID IN` in the main outer query. Which is what you'd want, since the subquery returns a list of all Model IDs that haven't had any orders since January 1st, 2015 (inclusive - so basically since December 31st, 2014 exclusive, as your requirements are), so those are the Models that should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am learning something!

Comment: @DonaldAlesson No problem! And great, I'm glad to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to fix exacly?
Performace?

or is the boudary the issue?

```
DELETE FROM Model
WHERE ID NOT IN
(  
    SELECT Model.ID
    FROM Model AS mo
    INNER JOIN Machines AS ma
        ON mo.ID = ma.ModelNo
    INNER JOIN Orders AS O
        ON ma.SerialNo = O.SerialNo
    WHERE O.OrderDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY mo.ID
);
```